# Rails has_secure_password: is it actually hashing the password in the DB?

Tags: security, bcrypt, password-hash, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Using typical Rails 4.1 app with `has_secure_password` and the `User` model has a `password_digest` column in the DB.  When I create a new user, I can still access the plaintext password in the console:

```
# in rails console
> u = User.new(email: "test@test.com", password: "password")
> u.save
> u.password => "password"
> u.password_digest => "xjdk..."
```

However, when I close the console session and start a new one, I can no longer retrieve the plaintext password:

```
# close above console session and open a new one
> u = User.find_by(email: "test@test.com")
> u.password => nil
```

I'm assuming that the plaintext password is only retrievable in the first situation because it's being stored in memory and when I call `u.password => "password"` it is retrieving the value from memory, NOT the database.

I had always thought `has_secure_password` stored the (salt + password) as a hash and I thought that meant it was theoretically impossible (if I can use that terminology) to reverse the `password_digest` and get the original password.

I'm just making sure my assumption that the password is stored as a real hash (ie, can't retrieve original password) is valid.  I've read the [Rails has_secure_password API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) but it didn't clarify my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct — the DB is only saving the hashed password, not the password itself. You can confirm this by accessing the database directly using the `read_attribute` method (http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read):

```
> u = User.new …
> u.read_attribute(:password_digest)
=> # Some hash
> u.read_attribute(:password)
=> nil
```

---

Incidentally, also make sure your `User` model does *not* have a `password` column. Otherwise it would save the `password` directly, defeating the purpose of hashing the password.

Comment: To clarify, the `password` attribute is an [instance attribute](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html). It will stick around as long as the user object is in memory. When you subsequently load that same user object, the `password` attribute will be nil.